# How to add new column with icon in bootstrap-table reorder row extenstion?

Tags: html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I want to reorder rows in my table, so I am using Bootstrap table extension [Extension Link](https://live.bootstrap-table.com/example/extensions/reorder-rows.html).
Basically, I want to add a [Menu Icon](https://fontawesome.com/v4.7/icon/bars) In the first column for each row, so that it makes sense when the user wants to change the order of rows manually. I have tried a lot of solutions and methods but it didn't for me. Is it possible to achieve my requirement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you tried ? Working exemple ?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to add information.